# One hot encoding huge 3D array

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

As the title my data looks like this:
`["test", "bob", "romeo"]` - etc just random words
I have converted them into numbers based on position in alphabet for each letter in the word so now it would be:

```
[[19, 4, 18, 19], [1, 14, 1], [17, 14, 12, 4, 14]]
```

and now I'd want to hot-encode it

```
tf.one_hot(featuresVectors, longestWordLen)
```

results in

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[512996,62,62]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running out of memory, meaning that there isn't enough memory left on your device to create such a tensor. Given that your batch size is `512996` and your depth dimension is `62`, you are trying to create a tensor of `512996x62x62xsizeof(float): ~7.34Go !`

Since the indices are never going to be greater than 26. You can try to use a smaller data type for this tensor, like `int8`:  `tf.one_hot(featuresVectors, longestWordLen, dtype=tf.int8)`.
That should take `512996x62x62x1: ~1.83 Go` on your device.

If your device still cannot allocate the tensor, then you'll have to reduce your batch size. (Aka the number of words)

Answer (score 2):

You basically run out of memory. Two approaches which could help are using less features (e.g count the words and just keep the top 10000 or so and a "unknown toekn" for therest) to make the onehot size smaller. Or you could use an embedding layer in your network and feed the integers directly.